# Solve for parameters to minimize expression complexity?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have a set of complicated expressions `cf[i]` with `i=1,...,35` that apart from constants depend on parameters `p[j]` with `j=1,...,19` linearly (each `cf[i]` depends only on a subset of `p[j]`). The parameters can be tuned arbitrarlily, so I would like to set the parameters to values such as to reduce the complexity of all `cf[i]` as much as possible. Can Mathematica do such an optimization? If yes, what is the syntax that I should use?

Comment: So you have a 35x19 matrix. Could you post it?

Comment: What is the measure of complexity?  `LeafCount`?